# how can i send a notification to customer when the product is back in stock

Tags: php, laravel

this is the code i have done i put it in the vendor update product function when the product is updated

```php
if ($product->stock >=1)
        {
        $user = DB::table('user_profiles')->leftjoin('wishlist', 'wishlist.user_id' , '=', 'user_profiles.id')->get('email');

        mail($user->email,'The book is available!!','Your book in wishlist is available. Please check it in your wishlist.');
        }
```

this is the function that vendor use to edit the product and save in database

```php
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['category'] = $request->mainid.",".$request->subid.",".$request->childid;

        if ($file = $request->file('photo')){
            $photo_name = time().$request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move('assets/images/products',$photo_name);
            $input['feature_image'] = $photo_name;
        }

        if ($request->galdel == 1){
            $gal = Gallery::where('productid',$id);
            $gal->delete();
        }

        if ($request->pallow == ""){
            $input['sizes'] = null;
        }


        if ($product->stock >=1)
        {
        $user = DB::table('user_profiles')->leftjoin('wishlist', 'wishlist.user_id' , '=', 'user_profiles.id')->get('email');

        mail($user->email,'The book is available!!','Your book in wishlist is available. Please check it in your wishlist.');
        }


        $product->update($input);

        if ($files = $request->file('gallery')){
            foreach ($files as $file){
                $gallery = new Gallery;
                $image_name = str_random(2).time().$file->getClientOriginalName();
                $file->move('assets/images/gallery',$image_name);
                $gallery['image'] = $image_name;
                $gallery['productid'] = $id;
                $gallery->save();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is issue  you are facing?

Comment: Email cannot send and i need to send the email by user_id from wishlist. is it impossible to get the email from another table?

Comment: you need to send multiple users? by this query you are able to get user records ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow laravel mail send documentation:

```
 $user = DB::table('user_profiles')->leftjoin('wishlist', 'wishlist.user_id' , '=', 'user_profiles.id')->select('email')->get();
 foreach($user as $usr){
     Mail::send('emails.wishlist', ['usr' => $usr], function ($m) use ($usr) {
         $m->from('Youremail@app.com', 'Your Application');
         $m->to($usr->email)->subject('Items are now available!');
     });
 }
```

Create a new view blade file in `resources` `->` `emails` folder as `wishlist.blade.php`

In the blade add your email body:

```
 'The book is available!!','Your book in the wishlist is available. Please check it in your wishlist.
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/mail

Answer (score 0):

First get your users email as Array

```
$users = DB::table('user_profiles')
->select('email')
->leftjoin('wishlist', 'wishlist.user_id' , '=', 'user_profiles.id')
->get()->toArray();
```

Send mail to multiple users.

```
Mail::send([], [], function ($message) use ($users) {
  $message->to($users)
    ->from('your_email_id')
    ->subject('The book is available!!')
    ->setBody('The book is available!!,Your book in wishlist is available. Please check it in your wishlist.');
});
```

OR

```
Mail::raw('The book is available!!,Your book in wishlist is available. Please check it in your wishlist.', function ($message) use ($users){
 $message->to($users);
});
```

Comment: Undefined variable: users what's the problem ??

Comment: in your query use $users

Comment: i changed $user to $users

Comment: forgotten this :  use ($users)

Comment: I'm sorry but this happened preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string

Comment: where you use : preg_match()